# Align checkboxes at 4 corners of an image

Tags: html, css

I have an image and want the user to pick the edges of the image.
The checkboxes must not overlay the image but touch it.
The other important thing is that the image's top and bottom border needs to be the top and bottom for the checkboxes too.

I made this image where blue is the image and red are the checkboxes:

[image]

I've been experimenting but I'm not too experienced:

http://jsfiddle.net/a6ksoqzr/1/

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 600px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  background-image: url("https://imagesvc.meredithcorp.io/v3/mm/image?url=https%3A%2F%2Fcdn-image.travelandleisure.com%2Fsites%2Fdefault%2Ffiles%2Fstyles%2F1600x1000%2Fpublic%2Fblue0517.jpg%3Fitok%3DV3825voJ&w=400&c=sc&poi=face&q=85");
}

.top-left {
  width: 50%;
}

.top-right {
  margin-left: auto;
}

.bottom-right {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-top: auto;
}

.bottom-left {
  width: 50%;
  margin-top: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <input type="checkbox" class="top-left">
  <input type="checkbox" class="top-right">
  <input type="checkbox" class="bottom-left">
  <input type="checkbox" class="bottom-right">
</div>
```

Comment: The easiest approach in this case would be to absolutely position the checkboxes

Comment: does the image have to be a background-image? and do you know it's size?

Comment: @xception no I actually had it as an <img> first, thought it'd be easier making it a div background

Comment: than you have a few options, make the image an <img> have no border, no padding, no margin, and using the flex layout put the image as row 2 column 2 of a 3x3 grid, make the whole thing a table and position the image in the middle, or make the image container relative and the checkboxes absolute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using absolute positioning you can align the check boxes

```
.container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 600px;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    position:absolute;
    background-image: url("https://imagesvc.meredithcorp.io/v3/mm/image?url=https%3A%2F%2Fcdn-image.travelandleisure.com%2Fsites%2Fdefault%2Ffiles%2Fstyles%2F1600x1000%2Fpublic%2Fblue0517.jpg%3Fitok%3DV3825voJ&w=400&c=sc&poi=face&q=85");
  }

  .top-left {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;

  }

  .top-right {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    right:0;

  }

  .bottom-right {
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    right:0;
  }

  .bottom-left {

    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is jsfiddle with ONE OF THE METHODS to solve the problem : http://jsfiddle.net/ArunK22/6c1nwthe/16/

You have to make your container as relative :

```
.container {
    position: relative;
}
```

And make the inputs to the position as absolutes:

```
  .top-left {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: -20px;
  }

  .top-right {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: -20px;
  }

  .bottom-right {
   position: absolute;
   bottom: 0;
   right: -20px;
  }

  .bottom-left {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: -20px;
  }
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Absolute positioned checkboxes will help you solve your problem.

```
  .top-left,
  .top-right,
  .bottom-left,
  .bottom-right {
    position: absolute;
    margin: 0;
  }

  .top-left {
    top: 0;
    left: -1em;
  }
```

Don't forget to position your wrapping container relatively. Otherwise absolute positioning won't work properly since absolute positions are always absolute to their next relative parent.

See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6x4kgjnr/).

Answer (score 0):

From what I read in your question and the comments. This should be, what you wanted.

```css
.container {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 600px;
  background-image: url("https://imagesvc.meredithcorp.io/v3/mm/image?url=https%3A%2F%2Fcdn-image.travelandleisure.com%2Fsites%2Fdefault%2Ffiles%2Fstyles%2F1600x1000%2Fpublic%2Fblue0517.jpg%3Fitok%3DV3825voJ&w=400&c=sc&poi=face&q=85");
  background-size = 100% 100%;
}

.top-left {
  position: absolute;
  top: -3px;
  left: -16px;
}

.top-right {
  position: absolute;
  top: -3px;
  right: -16px;
}

.bottom-right {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -3px;
  right: -16px;
}

.bottom-left {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -3px;
  left: -16px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <input type="checkbox" class="top-left">
  <input type="checkbox" class="top-right">
  <input type="checkbox" class="bottom-left">
  <input type="checkbox" class="bottom-right">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I added the spacer to have an idea how the layout of the page would look, html:

```
<div class="spacer">

<div class="container">
  <input type="checkbox" class="top-left">
  <img src="https://imagesvc.meredithcorp.io/v3/mm/image?url=https%3A%2F%2Fcdn-image.travelandleisure.com%2Fsites%2Fdefault%2Ffiles%2Fstyles%2F1600x1000%2Fpublic%2Fblue0517.jpg%3Fitok%3DV3825voJ&w=400&c=sc&poi=face&q=85"/>
  <input type="checkbox" class="top-right">
  <input type="checkbox" class="bottom-left">
  <input type="checkbox" class="bottom-right">
</div>

</div>
```

css:

```
 .spacer {
   padding: 30px;
   border: 1px solid gray;
 }
 .container {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
  }

  .top-left {
    position: absolute;
    right: 100%;
    top: 0;
  }

  .top-right {
    position: absolute;
    left: 100%;
    top: 0;
  }

  .bottom-right {
    position: absolute;
    left: 100%;
    bottom: 0;
  }

  .bottom-left {
    position: absolute;
    right: 100%;
    bottom: 0;
  }
```

using left: 100% for right positioning and right: 100% for left positioning is the best way in my opinion because this way you can position any elements regardless of their sizes

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5n70u86o/)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like below.

```
<style type="text/css">
  .container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 600px;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    background-image: url("https://imagesvc.meredithcorp.io/v3/mm/image?url=https%3A%2F%2Fcdn-image.travelandleisure.com%2Fsites%2Fdefault%2Ffiles%2Fstyles%2F1600x1000%2Fpublic%2Fblue0517.jpg%3Fitok%3DV3825voJ&w=400&c=sc&poi=face&q=85");
    position: relative;
    margin: auto;
  }

  .top-left {
    position: absolute;
    top: -3px;
    left: -17px;
  }

  .top-right {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -3px;
    left: -17px;
  }

  .bottom-right {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -3px;
    right: -16px;
  }

  .bottom-left {
    right: -16px;
    top: -3px;
    position: absolute;
  }
</style>

<div class="container">
  <input type="checkbox" class="top-left">
  <input type="checkbox" class="top-right">
  <input type="checkbox" class="bottom-left">
  <input type="checkbox" class="bottom-right">
</div>
```